# What would be an acceptable bit size for RSA encryption of an image? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I'm coding a encryption module using pycryptodomex and I have run into an issue regarding the plaintext being to long for image encryption (ValueError). For my image encryption I convert the image into bytes and then encrypt the bytes. Currently I am using a key-pair with a bit size of 2048. I have tried using a key size of 4096 which takes a significantly longer amount of time to generate and use (≈100s). My question is is there a more efficient algorithms for encrypting images apart from RSA or AES (I use both however I am only getting this error whilst testing the asymmetric image encryption) and how would I encrypt images using these algorithms. I have also though of alternatives to increasing the key size these are using a if statement to prevent the user from trying to encrypt an image that is larger than the limit of encrypting an image using a 2048-bit RSA key, in this case what is the image size limit for encrypting using this kind of key? Another alternative I have though of is using compression to make the image size smaller however I would like to avoid this as this may mean loosing image quality, if nothing else works would encrypting compressed images work in the same was as encrypting standard images.

Here is the traceback for the error:

```
$ python -m unittest Test_TIENC_REVISED.py
EEEE....
======================================================================
ERROR: test_decrypt_failure (Test_TIENC_REVISED.TestImageEncA)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\probm\Desktop\tienc\tests\Test_TIENC_REVISED.py", line 58, in test_decrypt_failure
    ciphertext = self.image_enc.encrypt(self.image_path)
  File "C:\Users\probm\Desktop\tienc\tests\tienc_revised.py", line 71, in encrypt
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(img_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\probm\Desktop\tienc\venv\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 115, in encrypt
    raise ValueError("Plaintext is too long.")
ValueError: Plaintext is too long.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_encrypt_decrypt (Test_TIENC_REVISED.TestImageEncA)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\probm\Desktop\tienc\tests\Test_TIENC_REVISED.py", line 50, in test_encrypt_decrypt
    ciphertext = self.image_enc.encrypt(self.image_path)
  File "C:\Users\probm\Desktop\tienc\tests\tienc_revised.py", line 71, in encrypt
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(img_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\probm\Desktop\tienc\venv\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 115, in encrypt
    raise ValueError("Plaintext is too long.")
ValueError: Plaintext is too long.
```

Here is the code I use to test the encryption (commented out code is what I previously had):

```
class TestImageEncA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.image_path = imgpath
        self.private_key, self.public_key = tienc_revised.generate_key_a_4096() #self.private_key, self.public_key = tienc_revised.generate_key_a()
        self.image_enc = tienc_revised.ImageEncA(self.public_key)

    def test_encrypt_decrypt(self):
        ciphertext = self.image_enc.encrypt(self.image_path)
        output_path = "decrypted_image.jpg"
        self.image_enc.decrypt(ciphertext, self.private_key, output_path)
        with open(self.image_path, "rb") as f1, open(output_path, "rb") as f2:
            self.assertEqual(f1.read(), f2.read())

    def test_decrypt_failure(self):
        wrong_key = RSA.generate(4096).export_key() #wrong_key = RSA.generate(2048).export_key()
        ciphertext = self.image_enc.encrypt(self.image_path)
        output_path = "decrypted_image.jpg"
        self.assertRaises(Exception, self.image_enc.decrypt, ciphertext, wrong_key, output_path)
```

Here is the main code for encryption:

```
class ImageEncA:
    """ asymmetric image encryption """

    def __init__(self, public_key):
        self.public_key = RSA.import_key(public_key)

    def encrypt(self, image_path):
        with open(image_path, "rb") as f:
            img_bytes = f.read()
        cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.public_key)
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(img_bytes)
        return ciphertext

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, private_key, output_path):
        private_key = RSA.import_key(private_key)
        cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
        img_bytes = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
        with open(output_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(img_bytes)
```

Here is the code for generating keys:

```
# Asymetric key generation
def generate_key_a():
    key = RSA.generate(2048)
    private_key = key.export_key()
    public_key = key.publickey().export_key()
    return private_key, public_key

# Symetric key generation
def generate_key_s():
    key = os.urandom(32)
    return key

# Asymetric key generation with a larger bit size
def generate_key_a_4096():
    key = RSA.generate(4096)
    private_key_b = key.export_key()
    public_key_b = key.publickey().export_key()
    return private_key_b, public_key_b
```

So how would I fix this problem?

Comment: It's a very muddled explanation you've provided but AES is plenty fast enough for encrypting images. If you want to take advantage of public key cryptography as well you need to use a [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) scheme.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk From what I understand I am getting the error because the size of the image is too big to encrypt so I am wondering how I can essentially solve this error. Additionally I can't have the key generation take too long as I'm planning to use this to encrypt images for a web app. Even with a 4098 bit key the I still get the same error - plaintext is too long. I'm wondering how to fix this.

Comment: My comment addressed that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I understand however the issue I'm currently having is concerned with RSA as denoted by the error message which I'm getting whilst testing  `TestImageEncA`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am using the PKCS1_OAEP cipher. The image I am trying to encrypt is 2000 bytes however by using RSA and 2048-bit key and SHA-256, the longest message I can encrypt is 190 bytes long, I'm wondering how to get around this. Is using a Hybrid encryption algorithm the only way to do this?

Comment: @Vey Using a hybrid encryption scheme here is the only _correct_ way to do it, if you want RSA to be involved (pure symmetric would be fine).  There's a somewhat obvious functional alternative, but it is much slower than hybrid encryption and leaves a bunch of non-obvious security concerns as an exercise to the developer.

Comment: @bartonjs yeah, in accordance to suggestions I have completely refactored my code to use AES to encrypt plaintext or images (using passlib's scrypt function to generate a key in order to make it more secure) and then RSA to encrypt the key. My only concern now is that if will be applicable in my use case (chat web-app) as it might take too long and I will have to limit file size anyways.